# Does redirecting from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com Avoids Duplicate Content On Google?

Tags: mod-rewrite, search-engine

I heared that if i don't redirect the user from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com it will causes duplicate content of my website on google & other search engines, is that happening? and What is the Mod rewrite Syntax to do it through .htaccess ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Duplicate Content?"

Comment: question for superuser may be.

Comment: this really belongs on the mythical "webmaster" part of the trilogy, which doesn't exist.. yet

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, a lot of webmasters are here, just look at tag "CSS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google (and other big searches) usually detects "full clone", especially without `www.` prefix. You can register site in google webmasters and select, will google use `www.` prefix for your site, or should it use only `domain.com`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google themselves](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html) (see the last paragraph), you don't have to worry about content duplication at all unless you're doing it on purpose to trick search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/). It's basically an interface for domain owners to control how Google indexes the site. There you can set up what's called a "Preferred Domain" which means that when Google will translate links from any of the DNS subentries to a single DNS name (i.e. example.com => www.example.com) and will not direct people to the others.

Answer (score 1):

htaccess alternative, [rel canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com" />
```